# Adding a counter in SAS based on multiple conditions

Tags: sorting, sas, counter, multiple-conditions

I would like to ask for help on a SAS problem involving a counter based on multiple conditions.

**I have a dataset that contains customer visits of sales employees. However, the dataset is organized by the tasks that were conducted during the visits, hence it can contain several entries for the same visit.** The visits itself can span across several days. Currently the dataset is sorted by a generic ID.

Please also find a screenshot of the dataset here: [Data extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb5pT.png)

I need to **introduce a counter that clearly identifies the entries that belong to the same visit**. The counter should be based on the following **conditions**:

- New visit counter for every new employee-customer combination.
- New visit counter for same employee-customer combination only if the following conditions for the dates are NOT true: 1) The entries are from adjacent days, and 2) one entry is not "embedded" in the entry of an ongoing visit

StartDate and EndDate in that sense define a time range, that is important for the classification of the respective entries.

This is the dataset (including the intended solution and comments for each entry that may help to clarify the conditions above):

ID  StartDate   EndDate EmployeeNo  CustomerNo  Intended Solution   Comment
1   06.01.2009  07.01.2009  1   5   1   Adjacent days
2   07.01.2009  08.01.2009  1   5   1   Adjacent days
3   08.01.2009  08.01.2009  1   5   1   Adjacent days
4   05.01.2009  06.01.2009  2   7   2   Adjacent days
5   06.01.2009  07.01.2009  2   7   2   Adjacent days
6   05.01.2009  09.01.2009  3   1   3   Embedded entry
7   08.01.2009  08.01.2009  3   1   3   Embedded entry
8   09.01.2009  13.01.2009  4   2   4   Adjacent days
9   13.01.2009  13.01.2009  4   2   4   Adjacent days
10  05.01.2009  13.01.2009  5   3   5   -
11  19.01.2009  23.01.2009  6   3   6   Separately, since different employee
12  05.01.2009  16.01.2009  6   3   7   Same employee and customer, but no adjacent day
13  02.02.2009  03.02.2009  7   8   8   Adjacent days
14  03.02.2009  04.02.2009  7   8   8   Adjacent days
15  22.09.2010  22.09.2010  8   4   9   -
16  22.09.2010  22.09.2010  8   4   9   -
17  21.09.2010  21.09.2010  9   1   10  Adjacent days
18  21.09.2010  24.09.2010  9   1   10  Adjacent days
19  12.01.2009  22.01.2009  10  6   11  Adjacent days
20  23.01.2009  23.01.2009  10  6   11  Adjacent days
21  12.01.2009  19.01.2009  10  6   11  Embedded entry
22  26.01.2009  26.01.2009  2   9   12  Same day
23  26.01.2009  26.01.2009  2   9   12  Same day
24  26.01.2009  26.01.2009  2   9   12  Same day
25  07.05.2012  07.05.2012  1   2   13  -
26  09.05.2012  09.05.2012  1   2   14  Separately, since no adjacent days
27  09.07.2013  09.07.2013  3   10  15  Adjacent days
28  10.07.2013  11.07.2013  3   10  15  Adjacent days
29  08.09.2014  08.09.2014  4   1   16  Adjacent days
30  09.09.2014  10.09.2014  4   1   16  Adjacent days
31  08.09.2014  08.09.2014  4   1   16  Adjacent days
32  15.09.2014  15.09.2014  4   1   17  Separately, since no adjacent days
33  05.09.2014  05.09.2014  5   7   18  Adjacent days
34  04.09.2014  05.09.2014  5   7   18  Adjacent days
35  01.06.2015  01.06.2015  7   4   19  Separate counter since no adjacent days
36  03.06.2015  03.06.2015  7   4   20  Separate counter since no adjacent days
37  11.06.2015  12.06.2015  7   4   21  Adjacent days
38  09.06.2015  10.06.2015  7   4   21  Adjacent days
39  09.06.2015  09.06.2015  10  4   22  Separately, since different employee but adjacent days
40  11.06.2015  12.06.2015  10  4   22  Separately, since different employee but adjacent days
41  10.06.2015  10.06.2015  10  4   22  Separately, since different employee but adjacent days

Before starting I have sorted my dataset by EmployeeNo, CustomerNo, StartDate and EndDate. Then I have tried to use several SET/BY and First.Variable combinations which allows me to correctly implement the employee-customer condition. However, I struggle with the date conditions.

Here is the current state of my code.

```
 Data Count_Visits;
   Set Data;
   BY EmployeeNo CustomerNo;

   Retain Counter;

   IF First.EmployeeNo THEN Counter +1;
   ELSE IF First.CustomerNo THEN Counter +1;

   Keep ID StartDate EndDate EmployeeNo 
        CustomerNo Counter;
 Run;
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
mabe

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far. Post your sample input and output data as text within your question, not as an image.

Comment: Include data as text, not images. If anyone wants to attempt a solution that they test they are required to manually type out your data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, just edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured out a solution myself. Probably it is a bit brute force, but it seems to work well for over 300k entries.

```
Data Count_Visits;
  Set Data;
  BY EmployeeNo CustomerNo StartDate Enddate;
    lag_Start = lag(StartDate);
    lag_End = lag(EndDate);
    lag_End1 = lag(EndDate)+1;

    lag2_End1 = lag2(EndDate)+1;
    lag2_Techn = lag2(TechnNo);
    lag2_Cust = lag2(CustNo);

    lag3_End1 = lag3(EndDate)+1;
    lag3_Techn = lag3(TechnNo);
    lag3_Cust = lag3(CustNo);

    lag4_End1 = lag4(EndDate)+1;
    lag4_Techn = lag4(TechnNo);
    lag4_Cust = lag4(CustNo);

    lag5_End1 = lag5(EndDate)+1;
    lag5_Techn = lag5(TechnNo);
    lag5_Cust = lag5(CustNo);

  Retain Counter;

  IF First.EmployeeNo THEN Counter +1;
    ELSE IF First.CustomerNo THEN Counter +1;
    ELSE IF StartDate GE lag_Start AND Startdate LT lag_End THEN Counter = Counter;
    ELSE IF StartDate LE lag_End1 THEN Counter = Counter;
    ELSE IF TechnNo = lag2_Techn AND CustNo = lag2_Cust AND StartDate LE lag2_End1 THEN Counter = Counter;
    ELSE IF TechnNo = lag3_Techn AND CustNo = lag3_Cust AND StartDate LE lag3_End1 THEN Counter = Counter;
    ELSE IF TechnNo = lag4_Techn AND CustNo = lag4_Cust AND StartDate LE lag4_End1 THEN Counter = Counter;
    ELSE IF TechnNo = lag5_Techn AND CustNo = lag5_Cust AND StartDate LE lag5_End1 THEN Counter = Counter;
  ELSE Counter +1;
```

Run;